Sequence of 2-cylinders converging to a segment in the Gromov-Hausdorff metric
Let $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of (compact) 2-dimensional cylinders with smooth Riemannian metrics with Gauss curvature at least $-1$ and geodesically convex boundary (equivalently, the second fundamental form of $\partial C_i$ is non-negative).
Assume $\{C_i\}$ converges to a segment in the Gromov-Hausdorff metric.
Does it follow that length of $\partial C_i$ tends to 0?

I believe the answer is "yes". A possible strategy could be the following:
By Yamaguchi's fibration theorem, for $i$ large enough the collapse is given by a locally trivial fiber bundle (smooth submersion) $C_i \to I$ where the fiber is a quotient of a torus by a finite group. By dimensional reasons, this can only be the circle. Thus the fibration is equivalent to the trivial one and thus the boundaries are fibers and the collapse is exactly sending its diameter to $0$.
Probably there are easier ways to show this.

I think that the Yamaguchi theorem is not applicable to manifolds with boundary, such as the segment $I$.

I think you can take the double and perform the same construction maybe?
